# Did I get a dead CPU?

Tags: cpu, shuttle

I have a shuttle SH67H3 that has had a pentium G620 as the CPU since I built it. I ordered an i3-3220T as an upgrade. I swap the CPUs, connect everything, hit power and...nothing. The fan spins but that's it. No POST or anything. I swap the G620 back in, this time do not connect the hard drives, and I get a short message along the lines of "no boot drive found"....makes sense, and I haven't fried the computer. I swap the new chip back in, and again, nothing at all happens besides the fan spinning. Did I just get a dud chip or is something else possibly going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intel Pentium G620 is **Sandy Bridge**. The Intel Core i3-3220T is **Ivy Bridge**. You will most likely need to update the BIOS for the motherboard before it can support that CPU.

Edit: Thanks @Mark Allen for the comment. I was googling the Shuttle SH67H3 when he posted and I found this [support page](http://us.shuttle.com/barebone/models/sh67h3.html). For the `Intel® Core™ i3-3220T Processor (3M Cache, 2.80 GHz)` you will need version `SH67H000.201` of the BIOS and BOM version 2.0.

Comment: I think MC10 is correct. Here's what the manufacturer says (tl;dr you need v2.0 of that mobo and they tell you how to check) http://global.shuttle.com/main/productsFaqDetail?faqId=2079

Comment: Aha! Thank you both. Very luckily, I have the 2.0 mobo.

Comment: For completeness, instructions to flash the BIOS: http://www.shuttle.eu/fileadmin/resources/support/faq/attachments/Ivy_Bridge_Support_e.pdf